# Laravel : get attribute accessor only for specific routes

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have the following `Event` model :

I want to get `from` & `to` dates in `'M d, Y'` format **only** when calling `/api/events` or `/api/events/{id}` otherwise usual `'Y-m-d H:i:s'` format

My current code

App\Event

```
class Event extends Model
{

    protected $casts = [
        'from' => 'datetime',
        'to' => 'datetime'
    ];

    public function getFromAttribute($value)
    {
        return Carbon::parse($value)->format('M d, Y');
    }

    public function getToAttribute($value)
    {
        return Carbon::parse($value)->format('M d, Y');
    }
}
```

Api\EventController

```
//...
public function getList() {
   $events = Event::all();
   return response()->json($events);
}
//...
```

routes\api.php

```
//...
Route('events', 'Api\EventController@getList');
//...
```

Comment: Technically and architectural wise you should return the same format and let the consumer parse it...or make a `renderer` (an object that makes a formatted array with the desired formats)

Comment: I agree with the above, however, if you definitely need it to be a different format then I would suggest having a look at Resources: https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-resources.

Comment: Is it bad making if..else statement inside accessor method like : 
`if(request()->route()->getPrefix() == "api/events") {
            return Carbon::parse($value)->format('M d, Y');
}
return Carbon::create($value);`

Answer (score 0):

**This is a simple way to do it in your model**

```
 public function getImageAttribute($value)
{
    if (Str::contains(Request()->route()->getPrefix(), 'api')) {
        return url(Storage::url($value));
    }
    return $value;
}
```

Don't forget to import Str : use Illuminate\Support\Str;